# No internet - Windows is still setting up class configuration for this device (code 56)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, internet-connection, network-adapter

my windows couldn't detect any of the wifi connection in my area after network reset. My phone has access to the wifi so it's not my router issue.

I think the culprit behind this is my network driver showing the status description "Windows is still setting up the class configuration for this device Code 56)".

I have been spending hours looking for online solutions. None of it works. I seriously need help from you guys. Much appreciated.

Attempts tried:

1. Updating the networks drivers, doesn't work as it always end up with the code 56 error.
2. Uninstalled all vpn softwares to avoid drivers conflicts.
3. Restoring windows before the network issues happened

Here's a photo of my situation:

[image]

Comment: Did you try in Device Management to delete the wireless device and reboot?

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the reply. Actually I resolve this issue by updating the system offline with a usb. I tried uninstalling all of the network driver they will all automatically get installed again when i reboot. Also, I tried numerous suggestions online but no prevail. I'm commenting this just to let everyone know my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried numerous suggestions online but no prevail.

If you want to fix this without resetting your system. I suggest you to get a windows installation media on a usb and then update your broken system with the usb offline.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried the other solutions and  nothing works  then  if your computer has a network card (not built in to the motherboard) then you could remove the network card and boot the computer. Shut it down and  re-insert the card and  restart the computer.